# return(headers_referers) SyntaxError: 'return' outside function

Tags: python

```
def referer_list():
    global headers_referers     
    headers_referers.append('http://www.google.com/?q=')
    headers_referers.append('http://yandex.ru/yandsearch?text=%D1%%D2%?=g.sql()81%..')
    headers_referers.append('http://vk.com/profile.php?redirect=')
    headers_referers.append('http://www.usatoday.com/search/results?q=')
    headers_referers.append('http://engadget.search.aol.com/search?q=query?=query=..')
    headers_referers.append('https://www.google.ru/#hl=ru&newwindow=1?&saf..,or.r_gc.r_pw=?.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=fd2cf4e896a87c19&biw=1680&bih=882')
    headers_referers.append('https://www.google.ru/#hl=ru&newwindow=1&safe..,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=fd2cf4e896a87c19&biw=1680&bih=925')
    headers_referers.append('http://yandex.ru/yandsearch?text=')
    headers_referers.append('https://www.google.ru/#hl=ru&newwindow=1&safe..,iny+gay+q=pcsny+=;zdr+query?=poxy+pony&gs_l=hp.3.r?=.0i19.505.10687.0.10963.33.29.4.0.0.0.242.4512.0j26j3.29.0.clfh..0.0.dLyKYyh2BUc&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp?=?fd2cf4e896a87c19&biw=1389&bih=832')
    headers_referers.append('http://go.mail.ru/search?mail.ru=1&q=')
    headers_referers.append('http://nova.rambler.ru/search?=btnG?=%D0?2?%D0?2?%=D0..')
    headers_referers.append('http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D1%8D%D1%x80_%D0%..')
    headers_referers.append('http://ru.search.yahoo.com/search;_yzt=?=A7x9Q.bs67zf..')
    headers_referers.append('http://ru.search.yahoo.com/search;?_query?=l%t=?=?A7x..')
    headers_referers.append('http://go.mail.ru/search?gay.ru.query=1&q=?abc.r..')
    headers_referers.append('/#hl=en-US?&newwindow=1&safe=off&sclient=psy=?-ab&query=%D0%BA%D0%B0%Dq=?0%BA+%D1%83%()_D0%B1%D0%B=8%D1%82%D1%8C+%D1%81bvc?&=query&%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0q+=%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B6%D1%8C%D0%B5+%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%B0+%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%8B+%D1%87%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD&oq=q=%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA+%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C+%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0+%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B6%D1%8C%D0%B5+%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%B0+%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%DO%D2%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%8B+?%D1%87%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD&gs_l=hp.3...192787.206313.12.206542.48.46.2.0.0.0.190.7355.0j43.45.0.clfh..0.0.ytz2PqzhMAc&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=fd2cf4e896a87c19&biw=1680&bih=?882')
    headers_referers.append('http://nova.rambler.ru/search?btnG=%D0%9D%?D0%B0%D0%B..')
    headers_referers.append('http://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&rct=?j&q=&e..')
    headers_referers.append('http://help.baidu.com/searchResult?keywords=')
    headers_referers.append('http://www.bing.com/search?q=')
    headers_referers.append('https://www.yandex.com/yandsearch?text=')
    headers_referers.append('https://duckduckgo.com/?q=')
    headers_referers.append('http://www.ask.com/web?q=')
    headers_referers.append('http://search.aol.com/aol/search?q=')
    headers_referers.append('https://www.om.nl/vaste-onderdelen/zoeken/?zoeken_term=')
    headers_referers.append('https://drive.google.com/viewerng/viewer?url=')
    headers_referers.append('http://validator.w3.org/feed/check.cgi?url=')
    headers_referers.append('http://host-tracker.com/check_page/?furl=')
    headers_referers.append('http://www.online-translator.com/url/translation.aspx?direction=er&sourceURL=')
    headers_referers.append('http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator?uri=')
    headers_referers.append('https://add.my.yahoo.com/rss?url=')
    headers_referers.append('http://www.google.com/?q=')
    headers_referers.append('http://www.google.com/?q=')
    headers_referers.append('http://www.google.com/?q=')
    headers_referers.append('http://www.usatoday.com/search/results?q=')
    headers_referers.append('http://engadget.search.aol.com/search?q=')
    headers_referers.append('https://steamcommunity.com/market/search?q=')
    headers_referers.append('http://filehippo.com/search?q=')
    headers_referers.append('http://www.topsiteminecraft.com/site/pinterest.com/search?q=')
    headers_referers.append('http://eu.battle.net/wow/en/search?q=')
    headers_referers.append('http://engadget.search.aol.com/search?q=')
    headers_referers.append('http://careers.gatesfoundation.org/search?q=')
    headers_referers.append('http://techtv.mit.edu/search?q=')
    headers_referers.append('http://www.ustream.tv/search?q=')
    headers_referers.append('http://www.ted.com/search?q=')
    headers_referers.append('http://funnymama.com/search?q=')
    headers_referers.append('http://itch.io/search?q=')
    headers_referers.append('http://jobs.rbs.com/jobs/search?q=')
    headers_referers.append('http://taginfo.openstreetmap.org/search?q=')
    headers_referers.append('http://www.baoxaydung.com.vn/news/vn/search&q=')
    headers_referers.append('https://play.google.com/store/search?q=')
    headers_referers.append('http://www.tceq.texas.gov/@@tceq-search?q=')
    headers_referers.append('http://www.reddit.com/search?q=')
    headers_referers.append('http://www.bestbuytheater.com/events/search?q=')
    headers_referers.append('https://careers.carolinashealthcare.org/search?q=')
    headers_referers.append('http://jobs.leidos.com/search?q=')
    headers_referers.append('http://jobs.bloomberg.com/search?q=')
    headers_referers.append('https://www.pinterest.com/search/?q=')
    headers_referers.append('http://millercenter.org/search?q=')
    headers_referers.append('https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=')
    headers_referers.append('http://www.evidence.nhs.uk/search?q=')
    headers_referers.append('http://www.shodanhq.com/search?q=')
    headers_referers.append('http://ytmnd.com/search?q=')
    headers_referers.append('http://www.google.com/?q=')
    headers_referers.append('http://www.google.com/?q=')
    headers_referers.append('http://www.google.com/?q=')
    headers_referers.append('http://www.usatoday.com/search/results?q=')
    headers_referers.append('http://engadget.search.aol.com/search?q=')
    headers_referers.append('https://steamcommunity.com/market/search?q=')
    headers_referers.append('http://filehippo.com/search?q=')
    headers_referers.append('http://www.topsiteminecraft.com/site/pinterest.com/search?q=')
    headers_referers.append('http://eu.battle.net/wow/en/search?q=')
    headers_referers.append('http://engadget.search.aol.com/search?q=')
    headers_referers.append('http://careers.gatesfoundation.org/search?q=')
    headers_referers.append('http://techtv.mit.edu/search?q=')
    headers_referers.append('http://www.ustream.tv/search?q=')
    headers_referers.append('http://www.ted.com/search?q=')
    headers_referers.append('http://funnymama.com/search?q=')
    headers_referers.append('http://itch.io/search?q=')
    headers_referers.append('http://jobs.rbs.com/jobs/search?q=')
    headers_referers.append('http://taginfo.openstreetmap.org/search?q=')
    headers_referers.append('http://www.baoxaydung.com.vn/news/vn/search&q=')
    headers_referers.append('https://play.google.com/store/search?q=')
    headers_referers.append('http://www.tceq.texas.gov/@@tceq-search?q=')
    headers_referers.append('http://www.reddit.com/search?q=')
    headers_referers.append('http://www.bestbuytheater.com/events/search?q=')
    headers_referers.append('https://careers.carolinashealthcare.org/search?q=')
    headers_referers.append('http://jobs.leidos.com/search?q=')
    headers_referers.append('http://jobs.bloomberg.com/search?q=')
    headers_referers.append('https://www.pinterest.com/search/?q=')
    headers_referers.append('http://millercenter.org/search?q=')
    headers_referers.append('https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=')
    headers_referers.append('http://www.evidence.nhs.uk/search?q=')
    headers_referers.append('http://www.shodanhq.com/search?q=')
    headers_referers.append('http://ytmnd.com/search?q=')
    headers_referers.append('http://www.google.com/?q=')
    headers_referers.append('http://www.google.com/?q=')
    headers_referers.append('http://www.google.com/?q=')
    headers_referers.append('http://www.usatoday.com/search/results?q=')
    headers_referers.append('http://engadget.search.aol.com/search?q=')
    headers_referers.append('https://steamcommunity.com/market/search?q=')
    headers_referers.append('http://filehippo.com/search?q=')
    headers_referers.append('http://www.topsiteminecraft.com/site/pinterest.com/search?q=')
    headers_referers.append('http://eu.battle.net/wow/en/search?q=')
    headers_referers.append('http://engadget.search.aol.com/search?q=')
    headers_referers.append('http://careers.gatesfoundation.org/search?q=')
    headers_referers.append('http://techtv.mit.edu/search?q=')
    headers_referers.append('http://www.ustream.tv/search?q=')
    headers_referers.append('http://www.ted.com/search?q=')
    headers_referers.append('http://funnymama.com/search?q=')
    headers_referers.append('http://itch.io/search?q=')
    headers_referers.append('http://jobs.rbs.com/jobs/search?q=')
    headers_referers.append('http://taginfo.openstreetmap.org/search?q=')
    headers_referers.append('http://www.baoxaydung.com.vn/news/vn/search&q=')
    headers_referers.append('https://play.google.com/store/search?q=')
    headers_referers.append('http://www.tceq.texas.gov/@@tceq-search?q=')
    headers_referers.append('http://www.reddit.com/search?q=')
    headers_referers.append('http://www.bestbuytheater.com/events/search?q=')
    headers_referers.append('https://careers.carolinashealthcare.org/search?q=')
    headers_referers.append('http://jobs.leidos.com/search?q=')
    headers_referers.append('http://jobs.bloomberg.com/search?q=')
    headers_referers.append('https://www.pinterest.com/search/?q=')
    headers_referers.append('http://millercenter.org/search?q=')
    headers_referers.append('https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=')
    headers_referers.append('http://www.evidence.nhs.uk/search?q=')
    headers_referers.append('http://www.shodanhq.com/search?q=')
    headers_referers.append('http://ytmnd.com/search?q=')
    headers_referers.append('http://www.google.com/?q=')
    headers_referers.append('http://www.google.com/?q=')
    headers_referers.append('http://www.google.com/?q=')
    headers_referers.append('http://www.usatoday.com/search/results?q=')
    headers_referers.append('http://engadget.search.aol.com/search?q=')
    headers_referers.append('https://steamcommunity.com/market/search?q=')
    headers_referers.append('http://filehippo.com/search?q=')
    headers_referers.append('http://www.topsiteminecraft.com/site/pinterest.com/search?q=')
    headers_referers.append('http://eu.battle.net/wow/en/search?q=')
    headers_referers.append('http://engadget.search.aol.com/search?q=')
    headers_referers.append('http://careers.gatesfoundation.org/search?q=')
    headers_referers.append('http://techtv.mit.edu/search?q=')
    headers_referers.append('http://www.ustream.tv/search?q=')
    headers_referers.append('http://www.ted.com/search?q=')
    headers_referers.append('http://funnymama.com/search?q=')
    headers_referers.append('http://itch.io/search?q=')
    headers_referers.append('http://jobs.rbs.com/jobs/search?q=')
    headers_referers.append('http://taginfo.openstreetmap.org/search?q=')
    headers_referers.append('http://www.baoxaydung.com.vn/news/vn/search&q=')
    headers_referers.append('https://play.google.com/store/search?q=')
    headers_referers.append('http://www.tceq.texas.gov/@@tceq-search?q=')
    headers_referers.append('http://www.reddit.com/search?q=')
    headers_referers.append('http://www.bestbuytheater.com/events/search?q=')
    headers_referers.append('https://careers.carolinashealthcare.org/search?q=')
    headers_referers.append('http://jobs.leidos.com/search?q=')
    headers_referers.append('http://jobs.bloomberg.com/search?q=')
    headers_referers.append('https://www.pinterest.com/search/?q=')
    headers_referers.append('http://millercenter.org/search?q=')
    headers_referers.append('https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=')
    headers_referers.append('http://www.evidence.nhs.uk/search?q=')
    headers_referers.append('http://www.shodanhq.com/search?q=')
    headers_referers.append('http://ytmnd.com/search?q=')
    headers_referers.append('https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=')
    headers_referers.append('http://www.google.com/?q=')
    headers_referers.append('https://www.facebook.com/l.php?u=https://www.facebook.com/l.php?u=')
    headers_referers.append('https://drive.google.com/viewerng/viewer?url=')
    headers_referers.append('http://www.google.com/translate?u=')
    headers_referers.append('https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=')
    headers_referers.append('http://help.baidu.com/searchResult?keywords=')
    headers_referers.append('http://www.bing.com/search?q=')
    headers_referers.append('https://add.my.yahoo.com/rss?url=')
    headers_referers.append('https://play.google.com/store/search?q=')
    headers_referers.append('http://www.google.com/?q=')
    headers_referers.append('http://www.usatoday.com/search/results?q=')
    headers_referers.append('http://engadget.search.aol.com/search?q=')
    headers_referers.append('http://' + host + '/')
return(headers_referers)
```

Thats My Code Its Giving Error

> return(headers_referers)
>   SyntaxError: 'return' outside function

what can i do i tried alot of solutions , please tell me the problem in the code.......... please note that all functions that i used append and return in it in the same file don't work and giving same error, i had some indentation errors and ifixed it and it didn't work too

Comment: You need to fix the indentation of `return`.

Comment: You may want to take a look at the `extend` method.

Answer (score 1):

The error is just what it says: your `return()` is outside your function. Python uses indentation to define code blocks, so for your `return` statement to be inside the function it must be indented. **So, just indent your `return(headers_referers)` so it's aligned with the `headers_referers.append()` above it.

In the comments, @Barmar suggested the possibility that your're using mixing tabs and spaces in your indentation. In python, you should always **indent with spaces**

Comment: return(headers_referers)
                           ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level
gave that when i indented it with headers_referers.append()

Comment: @AhmedShadyElsadany If you indented it correctly, you would not get that error.

Comment: @AhmedShadyElsadany Make sure you're consistent in use of spaces vs. tabs in indentation.